Concatenated Strings in cell produce extra space in iText
Concatenated string produces extra whitespace between words.
String cellLine = new StringBuilder()  
    .append("*********")
    .append("World")
    .append("***********")
    .toString();

Cell cell1 = new Cell(1, 3)
    .add(cellLine)
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .setBold();

table.addCell(cell1);

Actual Output is
********* World<    space    >***********

Expected Output
******************* World****************

Could someone please help as to how to get rid of this unwanted space in the actual output
Tried using StringBuilder to avoid spaces in the string when it is built. But it doesn't help.

It's not a concatenated string, it's just a string. There is absolutely no difference between String cellLine = new StringBuilder().append("*********").append("World").append("***********").toString(); and String cellLine = "*********World***********";

Sorry about the ambiguity. I meant when you declare and initialize String with StringBuilder, iText renders it differently as compared to a String declare and initialization like String cellLine = "World**". With the second declaration, it does not add space after the word "World" as compared to the StringBuilder way of initializing.

There must be something else happening. What I meant was there is ABSOLUTELY NO DIFFERENCE in the result between initialising the string variable using StringBuilder and using a direct string literal. See the proof.

So in other words, iText does not render a string initialized with StringBuilder differently than if it were initialized with a literal. Please provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example demonstrating the issue.
